# Why hbase does not support bzip2 compression?

Tags: hbase, bzip2

Why  hdfs support bzip2 compression but hbase does not support bzip2 compression?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because no one has wanted it enough to contribute the support for it.  bzip2 is very CPU intensive so is extra costly for HBase where you are more likely to be doing random reads and compactions that will cause repeated compression & decompression.  That said, if someone really wanted it and put up a patch for it, I'm sure it would be accepted.